# How does the gift Two-World Eyes work in comparison to Dual Senses?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken

The Dual Senses rule allows a Werewolf to see across the Gauntlet with two penalties, firstly they cannot see clearly, the vision they get is blurred and fogged.  The second penalty is of course not being able to see the side of the Gauntlet you're standing in.  The only way you can see clearly is by an exceptional success, but you still cannot see the realm you're standing in.

By my understanding the Two-World Eyes gift mitigates both of these two penalties and improves on the capabilities of an exceptional success.  The most notable portion of the gift is that you can see on both sides of the Gauntlet simultaneously.  I believe the "without penalty" portion of the gift states that you can see clearly while using the gift.  An exceptional success would then build on this allowing further increased perception by way of allowing scent or sound to be perceived as well.

My storyteller disagrees however.  He states that Two-World Eyes still suffers the penalty of being unable to see clearly, and on top of that even an exceptional success will not allow you to see clearly across the Gauntlet, only allowing additional (likely also hampered) perception types.  I was told that if I can find some sort of errata regarding this he would reconsider his stance.  I have yet to find any errata relating to Dual Senses or Two-World Eyes.

Which interpretation is more accurate (or are both incorrect)?  Does anyone know of an errata relating to one or both of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: Two World Eyes does not suffer from any perception penalties.

### Duel Sense (WTF Appendix 1, page 252)

#### To perceive into the Shadow (or the martial world if already in the Shadow)

- Roll Wits+Occult+Primal Urge - Gauntlet Strength

  - Irraka have +2 bonus dice to this from Auspice

    - as a Instant action.
    - Success: gets a vague impression of what is going on. Blurred forms, though "filthy frosted glass",
    - Exceptional Success: a more clear view. "as if seen though cloudy glass", . Which I interpret as being more like lightly misted as a car window can get on a cold night, but still clear enough to drive while the defogger is turned on.
    - Duration: Up to 1 turn
    - Duel senses actually never mentions "only being able to see the other realm".

      - Because of the text in TwoWorld Eyes, this may be assumed to be true.
      - But since it lasts only a maximum of 1 turn, unlikely to be a notable penelty.

        - since it states "up to one turn" it seems that you therefore could use it for a reflexive glance

## Two World Eyes (WTF, Crecent Moon Gifts 1, page 104)

- This is a gift, only available to the Ithaeur.
- Roll Withs + Occult + Wisdom
- as Instant action
- Duration = number of successes
- Success: The character can perceive both sides of the gauntlet (physical and  shadow) *without penalty*
- Exceptional success: can also either smell or hear both sides
- Dramatic Failure: Suffer the penalty of using Duel Senses for rest of the scene

  - As to whether there penalties are applied to your normal vision or to you perception of the other realm is questionable. I believe it is to your normal vision, but that doesn't matter.
- The presence or influce of a locus has no effect on the perception

## Arguments for why No Bluring for Two World Eyes

1. The dramatic failure clause of Two World Eyes, is to get the penalties from Duel Senses:

   - Duel Senses has no described *numerical* penalties, thus the penalties from Duel Senses mush be the "Frosted Glass".
   - Thus if the penalties are suffered for dramatic failure, why would they not be mentioned if they were also present if you succeed.
2. It is very usual for there to be limitation on a gift that are not explicitly mentioned (as is done in the dramatic failure clause).

   - Either in the ability itself
   - in a preceding paragraph
   - This limitation is only mentioned in a Appedix After.

     - this is not content people are expected to be well read up on, that is why it is in a appendix.
3. The presence or influence of a locus explicitly has no effect.

   - I attribute the bluryness of Duel-Sense to the gauntlet (though that is by implication).
   - gauntlet is weak at locus, so if it was like Duel-Senses, then it would be more clear at a locus.
4. This ability is meant to represent Ithaeur, being able to see better than most. So it should work noticeably better than not having this ability

There is no Errata because it is not incorrect.
it is slightly unclear, but White Wolf was generally not too good about publishing errata.
There are plenty of things much less clear that have no erratum.

**So, in short, I think your GM is mistaken.**
Perhaps you can encourage him to review these points, and his own understanding of the system.
If not, then you might wish to skip taking the first dot of Crescent Moon.